# ValueError: arange: cannot compute length

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute a metric of saliency map. The input is a predicted saliency map (heatmap) and fixation map (binary map).

The function was fine until I do a postprocessing as:

```
predictions[predictions < 0] = 0
scaled_predictions = (predictions - np.min(predictions)) / (np.max(predictions) - np.min(predictions))
```

I ran into this error but not knowing how to fix it:

```
<ipython-input-17-4d18bbcabb28> in run_metrics(model_type, trained_weights, vid_number)
---> 72             auc_borji_score.append( AUC_Borji(scaled_predictions[i], fixation[i]) )

<ipython-input-5-0f936e3c9c4f> in AUC_Borji(saliency_map, fixation_map, n_rep, step_size, rand_sampler)
    210     for rep in range(n_rep):
--> 211         thresholds = np.r_[0:np.max(np.r_[S_fix, S_rand[:,rep]]):step_size][::-1]
    212         tp = np.zeros(len(thresholds)+2)
    213         fp = np.zeros(len(thresholds)+2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    349                     newobj = linspace(start, stop, num=size)
    350                 else:
--> 351                     newobj = _nx.arange(start, stop, step)
    352                 if ndmin > 1:
    353                     newobj = array(newobj, copy=False, ndmin=ndmin)

ValueError: arange: cannot compute length
```

Full `AUC_Borji` code:

```
def AUC_Borji(saliency_map, fixation_map, n_rep=100, step_size=0.1, rand_sampler=None):
    '''
    This measures how well the saliency map of an image predicts the ground truth human fixations on the image.
    ROC curve created by sweeping through threshold values at fixed step size
    until the maximum saliency map value.
    True positive (tp) rate correspond to the ratio of saliency map values above threshold
    at fixation locations to the total number of fixation locations.
    False positive (fp) rate correspond to the ratio of saliency map values above threshold
    at random locations to the total number of random locations
    (as many random locations as fixations, sampled uniformly from fixation_map ALL IMAGE PIXELS),
    averaging over n_rep number of selections of random locations.
    Parameters
    ----------
    saliency_map : real-valued matrix
    fixation_map : binary matrix
        Human fixation map.
    n_rep : int, optional
        Number of repeats for random sampling of non-fixated locations.
    step_size : int, optional
        Step size for sweeping through saliency map.
    rand_sampler : callable
        S_rand = rand_sampler(S, F, n_rep, n_fix)
        Sample the saliency map at random locations to estimate false positive.
        Return the sampled saliency values, S_rand.shape=(n_fix,n_rep)
    Returns
    -------
    AUC : float, between [0,1]
    '''
    saliency_map = np.array(saliency_map, copy=False)
    fixation_map = np.array(fixation_map, copy=False) > 0.5
    # If there are no fixation to predict, return NaN
    if not np.any(fixation_map):
        print('no fixation to predict')
        return np.nan
    # Make the saliency_map the size of the fixation_map
    if saliency_map.shape != fixation_map.shape:
        saliency_map = resize(saliency_map, fixation_map.shape, order=3, mode='nearest')
    # Normalize saliency map to have values between [0,1]
    saliency_map = normalize(saliency_map, method='range')

    S = saliency_map.ravel()
    F = fixation_map.ravel()
    S_fix = S[F] # Saliency map values at fixation locations
    n_fix = len(S_fix)
    n_pixels = len(S)
    # For each fixation, sample n_rep values from anywhere on the saliency map
    if rand_sampler is None:
        r = random.randint(0, n_pixels, [n_fix, n_rep])
        S_rand = S[r] # Saliency map values at random locations (including fixated locations!? underestimated)
    else:
        S_rand = rand_sampler(S, F, n_rep, n_fix)
    # Calculate AUC per random split (set of random locations)
    auc = np.zeros(n_rep) * np.nan
    for rep in range(n_rep):
        thresholds = np.r_[0:np.max(np.r_[S_fix, S_rand[:,rep]]):step_size][::-1]
        tp = np.zeros(len(thresholds)+2)
        fp = np.zeros(len(thresholds)+2)
        tp[0] = 0; tp[-1] = 1
        fp[0] = 0; fp[-1] = 1
        for k, thresh in enumerate(thresholds):
            tp[k+1] = np.sum(S_fix >= thresh) / float(n_fix)
            fp[k+1] = np.sum(S_rand[:,rep] >= thresh) / float(n_fix)
        auc[rep] = np.trapz(tp, fp)
    return np.mean(auc) # Average across random splits
```

Since the postprocessing should only change the value of each pixel but not the number of pixels, I don't understand why this error happens.

Comment: That error message is coming from code you didn't post. Show a [mcve].

Comment: I think the problem occurs in numpy? I have posted code of the function

Comment: your code is virtually undebuggable. when working with other people you should never perform so many operations in one line. How do you pass code reviews like that? please break the line 'thresholds = np.r_[0:np.max(np.r_[S_fix, S_rand[:,rep]]):step_size][::-1]' to single operations and post which one actually causes the problem.

Comment: The code is taken from an academic repository. I totally agree with you

Answer (score 2):

According to the traceback the error occurs in

```
np.r_[0:np.max(np.r_[S_fix, S_rand[:,rep]]):step_size]
```

`r_` converts a `slice` into an array of numbers using `np.arange`.

The pieces of the problem line are:

```
np.r_[S_fix, S_rand[:,rep]]   # What is `S_fix`?  `S_rand`?
np.max(_)
np.r_[0:_:step_size]          # this uses `np.arange`
```

A web search and some experimenting shows that `np.arange(np.nan)` produces this error message:

```
ValueError: arange: cannot compute length
```

That means the `np.max(_)` must be producing `nan`, and that in turn means that either `S_fix` or `S_rand[:,rep]`  contain a `nan`.

So `saliency_map` must have some `np.nan` values

Comment: thanks. I have the same conclusion as you are after some trials and errors. Just don't have a solution yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing values after `predictions[predictions < 0] = 0`
maybe you need to equate it to some variable, for example:
someVariable = `predictions[predictions < 0] = 0`

I had the same error and I solved it by removing Nan values:
`df.dropna()`